# Make variables universally accessible in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

So when you make websites using Java you have something called a Session in which you can store any information you want basically for as long as that browser session is going on.

I'm fairly new with using ASP.NET MVC 3 and being able to pass around the right data at the right time is something that leaves me tied up quite often. For the most part I understand passing variables from views to controllers and back to other views.

But I was wondering if there's a way to make something that allowed to to let's say, grab a user's address from any view? I know there is `User.Identity.Name` built in and this is very handy for checking that a user is on their own page, etc. But is there any way to have a User object with custom information that is accessible anywhere?

I'm currently working on having a reputation system on my website (much like this website) where different amounts of reputation allow you to do different things. So in a lot of views I need to say "Hey, if the user has this reputation, let them see this feature." But this is extremely tedious if I have to pass in a user into every single view.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [HttpContext.Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

If you want more info on session and ASP.NET MVC, take a look at [this article](http://www.codethinked.com/aspnet-mvc-request-flow) to get a better understanding on when session is available during a request.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your custom class object is Session. Session will be available across requests.

Assuming you have a class like this

```
public class LoggedInUser
{
  public string DisplayName { set;get;}
  //Other relevant properties. relevant only not everything !
}
```

and you can store it in session like this

```
LoggedInUser objLoggedInUser=new LoggedInUser();
objLoggedInUser.DisplayName="Johnson";
Session["LoggedUser"]=objLoggedInUser;
```

Now wherever you want this, you can read it from session like this

```
LoggedInUser objLoggedInUser;
if(LoggedInUser objLoggedInUser=!=null)
{
  objLoggedInUser=(LoggedInUser)Session["LoggedUser"];
  // Now you can access objLoggedInUser.DisplayName
}
```

I would wrap this functionality into a function and call that function to get the data wherever i want.